# How to clear console permanently

Tags: javascript, console, console.log

So I'm making a game and I have it so the answer is input by the player through the console (if the console = answer they win). I want to have a function that clears the console and reset the variable vaules. So far the console is cleared but when you click another letter the previous letters come back.

```
function picked(letter){        
    word+= letter;
    console.log(word);
}

function ClearC() {
      console.clear();
}

<div class = "letter" id="a" onclick = "picked('a');">a</div>
<div class = "letter" id="b" onclick = "picked('b');">b</div>

<input type="button" class="button" onclick="ClearC()" value="Clear">
```

So my question is, is there a way to permanently clear the console so the player can start a new answer. I'm still very new to JavaScript so I'm aware I might be doing this completely wrong.

Comment: What you really want is to reset `word`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since word is not cleared, when they type it is logged to console again.

```
function ClearC() {
    word = "";
    console.clear();
}
```